# Add x number of days to a date with vba in excel

Tags: date, excel, vba

I am tring to add x number of days to a Long date with a pop up box.

```
Public Function AskForDeadlinePlus4() As String
    Dim strUserResponse As String

    strUserResponse = InputBox("Enter Validuntil Date: Add # of Days To Survey end date")
    strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(strUserResponse + I2, vbLongDate)
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = strUserResponse 'the 2, 10 is the cell reference for J2 - row 2, column 10.

End Function
```

Where Survey end date in cell I2.

When I run this I get (Googling how to do this I am tiring)

`4 + I2` (where `I2 = Friday, April 05, 2013`) **>>**  `Wednesday, January 03, 1900`

of course I need `Tuesday, April 09, 2013`

Thanks

Comment: `strUserResponse = FormatDateTime(DateAdd(d, strUserResponse, Range("I2")), vbLongDate)` - http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

Comment: Hello Tim, I tried your sugention, I get the error "Invalid procedure call or argument" not shure how to fix I am call like this at the end of another sub, Call AskForDeadlinePlus4, which works in its original

Comment: Also if I change `DateAdd(d, strUserResponse, Range("I2"))` to `DateAdd("d", strUserResponse, Range("I2"))` then I get a date output of "Wednesday, April 04, 2012" +4 >> "Wednesday, January 03, 1900"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you used the `DateAdd` function?

```
Sub DateExample()

Dim strUserResponse As String '## capture the user input'
Dim myDate As Date     '## the date you want to add to'
Dim numDays As Double  '## The number of days you want to add'


strUserResponse = InputBox("Enter Validuntil Date: Add # of Days To Survey end date")
numDays = InputBox("How many days to add?")
myDate = CDate(strUserResponse)

MsgBox DateAdd("d", numDays, myDate)


End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to do `myDate = CDate("d", CInt(strUserResponse, Range("I2"))`, as strUserResponse is the number of days to add to the date contained in cell I2?

Comment: A date is stored as a `long` value, so technically a value entered like `1.5` would not cause an error, but any non-numeric value like `"steven"` would cause a `mismatch` error. For a robust solution, yes, ultimately you need to add some logic to ensure that the user is passing allowable inputs, but that wasn't the question you asked :)

Comment: Hello, David, there are 2 Tim's here I am the one who posted the question.  How do I add the output to cell J2 I tried `ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = myDate` but I get the original date without the added days.  I would like to use the suggestion by the other Tim (as that was what I was tring to say) but that did not work either. If I add `myDate = CDate("d", CInt(strUserResponse, Range("I2"))` it turns red and says "Compile error Expected:)" Thanks to both

Comment: Try `ActiveSheet.Cells(2,10).Value = DateAdd("d", numDays, myDate)`

Comment: Thanks David, I used: ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = FormatDateTime(DateAdd("d", numDays, myDate), vbLongDate)

Answer (score 2):

I think this code is what your after using the `DateAdd(<base e.g. Day = "D">, <number>, <date>)` function:

```
Public Function AskForDeadlinePlus4() As String
    Dim strUserResponse As Date, iNumber As Long, rResponse As Variant

    AskForDeadlinePlus4 = "" 'set default value
    iNumber = CLng([I2])
    rResponse = InputBox("Enter Validuntil Date: Add " & iNumber & " Day(s) To Survey end date")

    If rResponse = False Then
        'no value entered
        Exit Function            
    ElseIf Not IsDate(rResponse) Then
        'no date entered
        Exit Function
    Else
        'valid date entered
        strUserResponse = DateAdd("D", iNumber, CDate(rResponse))
    End If

    AskForDeadlinePlus4 = FormatDateTime(strUserResponse, vbLongDate)    
End Function
```

Just a few points though:

- The input function will return the Boolean **FALSE** if no input is entered.
- The test you used above is a function and will return a value when used
- If you want to use in in another VBA code, `i = AskForDeadlinePlus4` is its usage;
- But you can also use it in a cell but only when necessary as with every calculation this will prompt an input and for every cell its in,  `=AskForDeadlinePlus4`; and
- Plus I've added a check to see if a date was entered as the user may not enter a valid one.

If you want to use in VBA:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    'the 2, 10 is the cell reference for J2 - row 2, column 10.
    ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = AskForDeadlinePlus4
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello glh, thank you for the code, when I run it I get the error "Type mismatch" not sure how to fix it.  Thanks

Comment: As soon as it starts to run

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DateAdd, which requires more typing, you could also use DateValue. Following would do it.

```
DateValue(strUserResponse )+I2
```

Another solution would be using the conversion function, CDate.

```
CDate(strUserResponse )+I2
```