# Add minutes to a time (hh:mm) in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a production schedule, and would like to add ex. 78 minutes to a time ex. 7:05 (am) in VBA. How would I go about doing this? This is what I have tried so far, but I'm getting an error 13 type:mismatch

```
Dim TUntilPump As Integer
Dim TFPump As Long, TStartPump As Long

TUP = 78
TFP = Time(0, TUP, 0)
TSP = Time(7,05,0) + TFP
```

I'm thinking it has something to do with my variable dimensions or the format of my times, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help is appreciated, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Use this, except change "d" to "n": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259166/add-x-number-of-days-to-a-date-with-vba-in-excel

Comment: @ScottCraner, yeah, I realized as soon as I commented and edited it to "n" while you were correcting me.

Comment: did either of these answers work? please select one as correct.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use the [DATEADD](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php) function:

```
TRP = dateadd("n",78,"7:05:00")
```

the "n" means minutes.

Comment: Why not "m"? What's "n" mean to VBA? (Just curious)

Comment: Because `m` is for `Month`

Comment: @BruceWayne I had to look it up, also.  Hence the link.  I wanted back up.

Comment: D'oh, should've checked there first. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Times should be considered **double** type vars for this. Time is a decimal portion of a day (1). 0.5 is noon and 0.666666 is 04:00 pm. I've found that the [TimeSerial function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws25fd2z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is good for constructing dates.

```
dim TFP as double, TSP as double, TUP as integer

TUP = 78
TFP = TimeSerial(0, TUP, 0)
TSP = TimeSerial(7, 5, 0) + TFP
'alternate
TSP = TimeSerial(7, 5 + TUP, 0)
```