# Increase or decrease a time cell by 15 min with buttons in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a time cell which I want to increase or decrease by 15 min by clicking up or down button. I figured it out with normal numbers but with time I couldn't make it with time.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of the `DateAdd`function

For example `Cells(1,1)` has your timestamp `1:00` then to add 15 mins:

```
Cells(2,1) = DateAdd("n", 15, Cells(1,1))
```

Or to minus:

```
Cells(2,1) = DateAdd("n", -15, Cells(1,1))
```

The `"n"` tells Excel to calculate with [minutes](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php), and some research would have brought you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34665030/add-minutes-to-a-time-hhmm-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example for cell **A1**:

```
Sub IncreaseTime()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value + TimeSerial(0, 15, 0)
    End With
End Sub

Sub DecreaseTime()
    With Range("A1")
        .Value = .Value - TimeSerial(0, 15, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```