# Excel Macro To Advance Date

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have a ton of excel sheets that each have 3 excel workbook tabs. On the last one there will be a ton of data but one column will be a date column with a bunch of different dates underneath. The date format will be MM/DD/YYYY. I need to advance each date ahead by 4 years.

I imagine that I will need to select the correct workbook, search for the particular column, and then loop to iterate through each value underneath that column to advance it, but the day itself needs to stay the same. For example, if its 10/05/2017, it needs to be 10/05/2021. Any suggestions or help would be great. Thank you in advance.

Thank you for the help, I realize I wasn't very helpful at all with my question. I'm very new to VB script and excel macros in general. I hadn't gotten how to search for the column itself as I would like it find the column no matter what the column value is (possibly search for a cell that says "Date" through the entire sheet?, I was just trying to add the 4 years to start with and couldn't find the function I needed. This is what I had from what I derived and seems like this is very wrong ha.

Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

```
  Set ThisCell = ActiveCell

    ThisCell = DateAdd("yyyy", 4, ColumnValueHere)

     ' Step down 1 row from present location.
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

  Loop
```

Comment: I would need to see your specific code but a simple algorithm is to take that date value and use `dateadd("yyyy", 4, ColumnValueHere)`  taken from [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php)

Comment: Suggestion:  Open Excel, Open the VBA window, write some code, come back with a question when you get stuck.  Also, for at least some helpfulness out of this comment, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259166/add-x-number-of-days-to-a-date-with-vba-in-excel and here: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dateadd.php

Answer (score 0):

You'll be wanting the [DateAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90).aspx) function

Try something like this:

```
Sub AddDates()

Dim lastRow as integer
Dim theSheetImWorkingOn as worksheet
Dim theColumnNumberForTheDates as integer

theColumnNumberForTheDates = 5 ' change this to be the column number you want
Set theSheetImWorkingOn = Sheets("Put your sheet name here")

lastRow = theSheetImWorkingOn.Cells(1000000, theColumnNumberForTheDates ).End(xlUp).row

For x = 2 to lastRow ' assuming your data starts on row 2

     theSheetImWorkingOn.Cells(x, theColumnNumberForTheDates) = DateAdd("yyyy", 4, theSheetImWorkingOn.Cells(x, theColumnNumberForTheDates))

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I was thinking the same sort of solution, but was waiting for them to provide some code to show where it is needed.

Comment: I've provided you a whole solution. What do you feel is missing?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into this. From what I'm reading, this means that the column value and row value has to be stated in the macro. Is there anyway to have it search the sheet for the "Date" value in one cell and then start advancing the date for each cell underneath it until the cell is empty? This way the it wouldn't matter which column or row the dates started on?

Comment: I was thinking that I could search the sheet for the "Date" value, once found, make that the "ActiveCell" and then in your code do x = ActiveCell.Row + 1 and theColumnNumberForTheDates = ActiveCell.Column

Comment: Yes there is, you'll want to use the Find method of the Range class, details here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx. There are various tutorials for this method on the web, here's two of them: https://blog.udemy.com/excel-vba-find/ and http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/find-method.htm